# Symbol for null proposition in mathematical logic

Tags: logic, notation

Is there a symbol in mathematical logic expressing a null statement?
That is an equivalent expression to:
$$p\land\lnot p$$

Comment: I've seen $\bot$, as opposed to $\top$ for tautology.
Check this [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols)

Comment: $\bot$, $F$ or $0$, depending on how you do represent truth/tautology ($\top$, $V$ or $1$.)

Comment: So is this called a universal fallacy?

Comment: @Archimedesprinciple I've heard it called "absurdity" and "contradiction;" I slightly prefer the former.

Comment: See [False (or : *falsum*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_(logic)).

Answer (score 0):

There are several. The ones I've seen most often are $\bot$ and $0.$ Ultimately, they all represent contradiction. The kicker is that the [Principle of Explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion) shows that a contradiction implies (or, from a [Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) standpoint, is "less than or equal to") all other statements.